# Spanish for "Of course"

Tags: traducción, modismos

As I remember from my basic Spanish class, my teacher used to use the phrase **Claro que si** for the English phrase **Of course**. But, most of the translators like Google translate and all show the following results: *Por supuesto*, *Desde luego*, *Claro está* etc.

I was wondering how actually do we say Of course in Spanish language(Spoken in Spain)? And, which one is actually the closest to Of course in literal meaning?

Comment: mi traducción humorística: "pero por supollo"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways to say "of course" in Spanish, just as there are in English.  "Of course" is an idiomatic expression, which means it cannot be translated literally ('de curso' doesn't really mean anything in Spanish).

English (some are context-dependent):

> - Of course
> - Absolutely
> - D'uh
> - Yes
> - Yeah
> - Clearly
> - Without a doubt
> - Undoubtedly
> - It goes without saying
> - Sure / Surely
> - Naturally
> - etc...

Spanish (again, some are context-dependent):

> - Claro que sí
> - Claro
> - Sí
> - Definitivamente
> - Por supuesto
> - Desde luego
> - Claro está
> - Sin duda
> - Naturalmente
> - Seguro
> - etc...

Comment: <removed obsolete comments>